# How to remove apps from a keystore?

Tags: android

I want to sell one of my apps, but I've signed ed it with the same keystore that I used for other apps. How can I remove the other apps from the keystore?

Comment: I can't understand you. You use same key or different key (in the same keystore)?

Comment: @waxtah different key in the same keystore

Comment: @code578841441 I don't think you can.

Comment: ok. Then  you can use keytool http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

Comment: And don't forget make backup your keystore.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using [KeyStore Explorer](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/)